# The Correct Way to Type React Navigation Drawer

Tags: typescript, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v6

WHat's the correct way to type RNavigation, currently I am doing this on The App

```
export type DrawerNavigatorType = {
  Store: unknown;
  ImagesStudio: { images: string[] }; //
};

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigator = () =>  (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Store"
        component={StoreNavigator}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="ImagesStudio"
        component={ImageStudioScreen}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
```

and in the screen

```
type Prop = DrawerScreenProps<DrawerNavigatorType, "ImagesStudio">;
```

but I keep getting

```
Type '({ navigation, route }: Prop) => React.JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ScreenComponentType<ParamListBase, "ImagesStudio"> | undefined'.
  Type '({ navigation, route }: Prop) => React.JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
    Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Prop': navigation, routets(2322)
types.d.ts(318, 5): The expected type comes from property 'component' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteConfig<ParamListBase, "ImagesStudio", DrawerNavigationState<ParamListBase>, DrawerNavigationOptions, DrawerNavigationEventMap>'
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
```

to

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator<DrawerNavigatorType>();
```